# Trying to apply pan gesture to UITableViewCell but failed, why?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, gesture, uipangesturerecognizer

So I learned how to make a pan gesture on a picture in view, moving it around. Then I try to do the same thing with TableViewCell: moving it horizontally with a pan gesture, it just fails to react:

So I created `TableViewController.swift`, set up common stuff to make sure it runs properly and shows a list of data with dynamic table cell.
Code:

```
var todoItems = [TodoItem]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    createSomeData()
}
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return todoItems.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(constant.cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TodoTableViewCell
    cell.todoItem = todoItems[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Then I pick up `Pan Gesture Reconizer` from palette, drop it on tableviewcell, make sure it connects in connection inspector, then, ctrl + drag `Pan Gesture Reconizer` into `TableViewController.swift` :

```
@IBAction func handlePan(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let transition = gesture.translationInView(self.view)
    switch gesture.state{
    case .Changed:
        if let view = gesture.view {
            view.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x + transition.x, y: view.center.y)
        }
        gesture.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)

    default:break
    }

}
```

It doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `PanGesture` programatically with below code,

```
var panRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

    self.panRecognizer = tableView?.panGestureRecognizer;
    self.panRecognizer .addTarget(self, action: "pan:")
    tableView?.addGestureRecognizer(self.panRecognizer)

}

func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func pan(rec:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    println("PanGesture Activated")
}
```

Hope this will help you.